# Repat the rows n times when column data is present

Tags: google-sheets-formula

[Make a copy of sheet here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1JNuCHsA3rcd0xEVe-Zm9nQq14gAI87vkdY96IXXYGFE/copy)

I have an input as shown here
[image]

The expected output is
[image]

The A to G column data needs to be repeated in the rows n times
where n is the count of items present in the range H to Q

For example the 5th row A4  B4  H6  D4  E4  F4  G4 is repeated 5 times since H5 to Q5 column has 5 entries for the 5th row

I have tried with
`=ArrayFormula(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(QUERY({A1:G10,TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(REPT(CONCATENATE(H1:Q1&","),COUNTA(H1:Q1)),","))},"Select * ")),","))))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try:

```
=index(let(Σ,{"","","","","","",""},Ξ,H2:index(Q:Q,match(2,1/(byrow(A1:G14,lambda(Σ,textjoin("",1,Σ)))<>""))),Δ,byrow(Ξ,lambda(Σ,max(1,counta(Σ)))),Γ,byrow(Ξ,lambda(Σ,if(counta(Σ)=0,"",Σ))),
          {query(reduce(Σ,sequence(counta(A2:A14)),lambda(a,c,{a;if(sequence(index(Δ,c)),index(A2:G14,c))})),"offset 1"),
          substitute(tocol(Γ,1),"","")}))
```

OR

```
=index(let(Σ,match(2,1/(byrow(A1:G14,lambda(Σ,textjoin("",1,Σ)))<>"")),
          {iferror(split(tocol(map(byrow(A2:index(G:G,Σ),lambda(Σ,textjoin("|",1,Σ))),byrow(H2:index(Q:Q,Σ),lambda(Σ,max(1,counta(Σ)))),lambda(a,b,wraprows(a,b,a))),1),"|")),
          substitute(tocol(byrow(H2:index(Q:Q,Σ),lambda(Σ,if(counta(Σ)=0,"",Σ))),1),"","")}))
```

[image]